# Find Shortest Part of Sentence containing given words

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Ex:
 if there is a sentence given: 
`My name is not eugene. my pet name is not eugene.` 
And we have to search the smallest part in the sentence that Contains the given words
**my** and **eugene**
then the answer will be 
`eugene. my`. 
No need to check the uppercase or lowercase or special charaters or numerics. 
I have pasted my code but getting wrong answer for some test cases.

can any one have any idea what is the problem with the code . I don't have the test case for which it is wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ShortestSegment 
{
static String[] pas;
static String[] words;
static int k,st,en,fst,fen,match,d;
static boolean found=false;
static int[] loc;
static boolean[] matches ;
public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    pas = in.readLine().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "").split(" ");
    k = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    words = new String[k];
    matches = new boolean[k];
    loc = new int[k];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        words[i] = in.readLine();
    }
    en = fen = pas.length;
    find(0);
    if(found==false)
    System.out.println("NO SUBSEGMENT FOUND");
    else
    {
        for(int j=fst;j<=fen;j++)
            System.out.print(pas[j]+" ");
    }

}
private static void find(int min)
{
    if(min==pas.length)
        return;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(pas[min].equalsIgnoreCase(words[i]))
        {
            if(matches[i]==false)
            {
                loc[i]=min;
                matches[i] =true;
                match++;
            }
            else
            {
                    loc[i]=min;
            }
            if(match==k)
            {
                en=min;
                st = min();
                found=true;
                if((fen-fst)>(en-st))
                {
                    fen=en;
                    fst=st;
                }
                match--;
                matches[getIdx()]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    find(min+1);
}
private static int getIdx()
{
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(pas[st]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
private static int min()
{
    int min=loc[0];
    for(int i=1;i<loc.length;i++)
        if(min>loc[i])
            min=loc[i];
    return min;
}


}
```

Comment: In your example, the shortest substring containing both words is not what you say.  It is "eugene. my".  And though your program strips the punctuation, it seems to find that properly.  This is really not possible to diagnose without knowing the failing test case.

Comment: yes the answer is "eugene. my" 
sorry for mistake

Comment: Is it possible that the input words would contain a repeated word?  (e.g. if the given words were "my","my")

Answer (score 0):

The code you've given will produce incorrect output for the following input. I'm assuming, the word length also matters when you want to 'Find Shortest Part of Sentence containing given words'

> String: 'My firstname is eugene. My fn is eugene.' 
>   Number of search strings: 2 
>   string1: 'my' 
>   string2: 'is' 
>   Your solution is: 'My firstname is' 
>   The correct answer is: 'My fn is'

The problem in your code is, it considers both 'firstname' and 'fn' as same length. In the comparison `(fen-fst)>(en-st)` you're only considering whether the number of words has minimized and not whether the word lengths has shortened.

Comment: Actually in the problem we have to find First Shortest part in the sentence and the shortest part is considered w.r.t words not the characters.

Comment: @omprakash Do you have an example where it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

the following codes (junit):

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    final String s = "My name is not eugene. my pet name is not eugene.";
    final String tmp = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ");//here we need the placeholder (blank)
    final String w1 = "my "; // leave a blank at the end to avoid those words e.g. "myself", "myth"..
    final String w2 = "eugene ";//same as above
    final List<Integer> l1 = getList(tmp, w1); //indexes list
    final List<Integer> l2 = getList(tmp, w2);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    final int[] idx = new int[] { 0, 0 };

    //loop to find out the result
    for (final int i : l1) {
        for (final int j : l2) {
            if (Math.abs(j - i) < min) {
                final int x = j - i;
                min = Math.abs(j - i);
                idx[0] = j - i > 0 ? i : j;
                idx[1] = j - i > 0 ? j + w2.length() + 2 : i + w1.length() + 2;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("indexes: " + Arrays.toString(idx));
    System.out.println("result: " + s.substring(idx[0], idx[1]));
}

private List<Integer> getList(final String input, final String search) {
    String t = new String(input);
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int tmp = 0;
    while (t.length() > 0) {
        final int x = t.indexOf(search);

        if (x < 0 || x > t.length()) {
            break;
        }
        tmp += x;
        list.add(tmp);
        t = t.substring(search.length() + x);

    }
    return list;

}
```

give output:

```
indexes: [15, 25]
result: eugene. my
```

I think the codes with inline comments are pretty easy to understand. basically, playing with index+wordlength.

**Note**

- the "Not Found" case is not implemented.
- codes are just showing the
  idea, it can be optimized. e.g. at least one abs() could be saved. 
  etc...

hope it helps.

Comment: Your Code is correct but it is just for the example i have given 
Not generalized there could be many Words to be found in the Sentence.
which are "my" and "eugene" here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be handled in another way :
First , find a matching result , and minimize the bound to the current result and then find a matching result from the current result .It can be coded as follows:

```
/**This method intends to check the shortest interval between two words
 * @param s : the string to be processed at
 * @param first : one of the words
 * @param second : one of the words
 */
public static void getShortestInterval(String s , String first , String second)
{
    String situationOne = first + "(.*?)" + second;
    String situationTwo = second + "(.*?)" + first;

    Pattern patternOne = Pattern.compile(situationOne,Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern patternTwo = Pattern.compile(situationTwo,Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer.MAX_VALUE,-1,-1));
    /**first , test the first choice*/
    Matcher matcherOne = patternOne.matcher(s);
    findTheMax(first.length(),matcherOne, result);
    /**then , test the second choice*/
    Matcher matcherTwo = patternTwo.matcher(s);
    findTheMax(second.length(),matcherTwo,result);

    if(result.get(0)!=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        System.out.println("The shortest length is " + result.get(0));
        System.out.println("Which start @ " + result.get(1));
        System.out.println("And end @ " + result.get(2));
    }else
        System.out.println("No matching result is found!");
}

private static void findTheMax(int headLength , Matcher matcher , List<Integer> result) 
{
    int length = result.get(0);
    int startIndex = result.get(1);
    int endIndex = result.get(2);

    while(matcher.find())
    {
        int temp = matcher.group(1).length();
        int start = matcher.start();
        List<Integer> minimize = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer.MAX_VALUE,-1,-1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group().substring(headLength));
        findTheMax(headLength, matcher.pattern().matcher(matcher.group().substring(headLength)), minimize);
        if(minimize.get(0) != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        {
            start = start + minimize.get(1) + headLength;
            temp = minimize.get(0);
        }

        if(temp<length)
        {
            length = temp;
            startIndex = start;
            endIndex = matcher.end();
        }
    }

    result.set(0, length);
    result.set(1, startIndex);
    result.set(2, endIndex);
}
```

Note that this can handle two situations , regardless of the sequence of the two words!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Knuth Morris Pratt` algorithm to find indexes of all occurrences of every given word in your text. Imagine you have text of length N and M words (w1 ... wM). Using `KMP` algorithm you can get array:

```
occur = string[N];
occur[i] = 1, if w1 starts at position i
...
occur[i] = M, if wM starts at position i
occur[i] = 0, if no word from w1...wM starts at position i
```

you loop through this array and from every non-zero position search forward for other M-1 words.

This is approximate pseudocode. Just to understand the idea. It definitely won't work if you just recode it on java:

```
for i=0 to N-1 {
 if occur[i] != 0 {
  for j = i + w[occur[i] - 1].length - 1 { // searching forward
   if occur[j] != 0 and !foundWords.contains(occur[j]) {
    foundWords.add(occur[j]);
    lastWordInd = j;
    if foundWords.containAllWords() break;
   }
   foundTextPeaceLen = j + w[occur[lastWordInd]].length - i;
   if foundTextPeaceLen < minTextPeaceLen {
    minTextPeaceLen = foundTextPeaceLen;
    // also remember start and end indexes of text peace
   }
  }
 }
}
```